# Angular Webpack - appropriate loader for .js.map

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an Angular app that is currently uses...

Angular 4.4.4
Webpack 1.13.0
TypeScript 2.2

It uses a package called ngx-facebook v2.4.0.

When I try to build I am getting the below error...

```
WARNING in ./~/ngx-facebook/dist/umd/models/ui-params.js.map
Module parse failed: C:...\node_modules\ngx-facebook\dist\umd\models\ui-params.js.map Unexpected token (1:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:10)
```

What sort of loader do I need to get around this error?

Comment: mmmm .. i don't know extaclty..but af i know .map files are not code file (just to map source files .. for typescript to js ..so you can debug the ts files..) so try maybe to EXCLUDE them from the webpack process (i think with some regular express like --> !*.map

Answer (score 0):

> What sort of loader do I need to get around this error

`.js.map` files should *not* be loaded.

## Fix

Something is importing the file .e.g `import * as foo from "./somewhere/some.js.map"`. Find and delete this import.